# Using Unity3d Scene with a PhoneGap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, 3d, unity-game-engine

We are working on a Mobile Application which has to be developed on IOS and Android Platforms. Most of the application is straight forward which is display content from a back end CMS system for which we are considering using PhoneGap. The application has one module in which the user can browse through a virtual house and be able to modify colors / replace a particular item like a chair etc. This can be easily done using Unity3d which we have in place. Using Unity3d for the whole application is probably going to be an overkill and there will be a lot of effort required on the Application Front or if we go the PhoneGap route managing the 3d thing is going to be a challenge.

The question I have is if there is any way we can export the Unity Scene and use it in a PhoneGap build since we will get best of both packages? If not that what are the options to get Unity3d working (UI and Services for Application) for doing an Application or doing some stuff with PhoneGap which helps to get the 3d part sorted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some people have have been able to edit the resulting XCode or Eclipse projects. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/3LKvtPWxNRk/lgisDBvPNNgJ This isn't easy, and will likely break when Unity changes its output.

Comment: Yes that's the last bet. But It is very tricky and cumbersome not worth the effort unless you are left with no other option.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out he solution.

Using Phonegap completely. For the 3d Module using Panorama image and displaying it using https://github.com/nicekei/jQuery-html5-canvas-panorama-plugin for interactivity. There are many other plugins available for jquery and mobile friendly. I choose to use the above one. You can find more on http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-panorama-image-display-plugins/. For walk through using annotations to link it to another page which will give a 3D Panorama for that room.

You can render stills from a 3d software and stitching them using any Panoramic stitcher Photoshop also does the job. Hope it helps.